# Реализация перетаскивания элементов мышью (изменение порядка элементов в блоке)

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Хочу реализовать подобную вещь (как на фото), чтобы можно было брать элемент и менять его местоположение в группе с другими элементами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Comment: Я использовал https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable, пример: https://github.com/w3lifer/crx-context-menu-search/blob/master/js/options.js#L56